# Can a field reference two different tables?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, relationship

In MySQL, suppose I have a field in `table1` that will take either '1' or '2' as a value. If it's '1' I want it to point to `table2` and if it's '2' I want it to point to `table3`. Is this possible?

Comment: yes its possible. or you want the cake solution ?

Comment: Write two queries that each join with the appropriate table and combine them with `UNION`. Or write two `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: @echo_Me What is a cake solution o.o?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need to put the whole thing into a case statement.

```
            Select case 
            when table1.value = 1 then table2.value
            when table1.value = 2 then table3.value
            end as 'value'
           FROM         table1 
INNER JOIN
tableq ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN
tableq ON table1.id = table3.id
```

That's the basic syntax.  What it's doing is saying, "if the value is THIS, I want the value from HERE".  And you can add as many WHEN as you like.

EDIT:  Added in the join.  that should be correct now.

Comment: The tricky part is the JOIN/ON clauses, which you've omitted.

Comment: You're right.  I'm actually working that out now.  Gimme a minute.

Comment: The question has already been closed as a duplicate, the answer is there.